# worklight 6.2 - server connection Issue

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Worklight 6.2 push notification is working for Android but not for iOS.

I followed the certification process when i installed in an iPad.
created certificates - apns-certificate-sandbox.p12.

after update, IP address not changing and also Push notification not working. I am also unable to sync worklight development server in Mac.

below error appearing in console:

```
[WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: //apps/services/reach
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: //apps/services/reach
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: //apps/services/reach
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:528)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:127)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:88)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:205)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:209)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:968)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1056)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4510)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:282)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:954)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:584)
at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:439)
at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:421)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[project PushNotificationsProject]
SRVE0190E: File not found: //apps/services/reach
[WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: //apps/services/reach
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: //apps/services/reach
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: //apps/services/reach
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:528)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:127)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:88)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:205)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:209)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:968)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1056)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4510)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:282)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:954)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
at com.i..
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really about push notifications...
You have an extra leading slash in the used URL: "//apps".

> [ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not
>   found: //apps/services/reach

Have you altered the server URL in any way?
Possible locations to look at:

- The Worklight Settings screen in the device (settings.app >> your-app-name)
- The Run As > Build Settings and Deploy Target window
- The native\worklight.plist file

In all, try removing the trailing slash at the end. The root cause is more likely to be in the Build Settings and Deploy Target window (which will generate the URL used in the other two options).

It will also help if you will explain the way you have built your project and any related changes you may have done in it that might have triggered this.